# To think of someone

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, vocabulary, translation-check, verbs

I have been trying to translate this English phrase into Latin properly, and I started to check it in some resources.

In [this text](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/cicero/fam6.shtml) it goes: "..., cum de tuis cogitas,...". And I have no idea why there is "cum" there but by the looks of it `cogitāre dē + ablative` seems to be valid.

Also [here](https://latin.packhum.org/loc/134/3/1/606-611,956-961,7586-7591@3#1) it only uses with `de + abl`, without `cum`.

So my questions are:

**a.** Is the correct translation of *`I am thinking of you`* in Latin *`dē tē cōgitō`*? If not, please indicate me into right direction. Am I using the wrong verb? What am I doing wrong?

**b.** Why is it used with a `cum` in Cicero's text? Does that change its meaning?

Comment: Welcome to the site! `de + ablative + cogitare` is indeed a pretty common construction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A:
Indeed, *de te cogito* is a valid construction and supported by the Cicero quote you have.

B:
Here *cum* is not a preposition but a conjunction.
It has no effect on how *de* works.

Comment: Ahh so something like: "cum dē tē cōgitō" would mean "when I think of you"? - Also thanks. :)

Comment: @Jacqueline Exactly! And you are most welcome.